# PHP Image Upload Checking Dimensions

Tags: php, html, image, upload

> How can I check the dimensions of an image after it has uploaded and
>   delete it if it does not match the dimensions I want?

So after digging around I find PHP cannot do dimensions. The solution I am following is:

1. Upload the file to the server
2. Use that new string and check
3. Delete it or continue with upload if it
   does not match width and height

This is my code. Can someone show me how to check the current file for dimensions and how to delete the folder and file if not matching?

```
# create our temp dir
    mkdir("./uploads/temp/".$user."/".$mx."/".$hash."/", 0777, true);
    # upload dir settup
    $uploaddir='./uploads/temp/'.$user.'/'.$mx.'/'.$hash.'/';
    $file=$uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

    # upload the file first
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file)) {
        # ok so check the height and width
        # if it is not the width and height assigned delete image and folder
        if (image height= and width =){
            unlink($file);
            rmdir($uploaddir);
            $result=0;
        } else {
        # image matches height and width message ok
            $result=1;
        }
    } else {
        # error uploading
        $result=$errormsg;
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your post at the beginning to explain what you're trying to do. Don't make us try to figure out what your goal is.

Comment: What do you mean by _So after digging around I find PHP cannot do dimensions_? What about `getimagesize()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: edited.. I don't know about getimagesize - it does not remove the image folder though. Can you show me an example?

Comment: To delete a file, use `unlink()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Comment: _it does not remove the image folder though_? What about `rmdir()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php. I think you need to rethink this question on your own first and if you have problems after that come back with proper code.

Comment: Thanks. I am using rmdir() and have updated my code. I just don't know how to use the getimagesize() and extract an if else from it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mkdir("./uploads/temp/".$user."/".$mx."/".$hash."/", 0777, true);
# upload dir settup
$uploaddir='./uploads/temp/'.$user.'/'.$mx.'/'.$hash.'/';
$file=$uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

# upload the file first
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file)) {
    # ok so check the height and width
    # if it is not the width and height assigned delete image and folder
    $size = getimagesize($files);
    $maxWidth = 500;
    $maxHeight = 500;
    if ($size[0] > $maxWidth || $size[1] > $maxHeight)
    {
        unlink($file);
        rmdir("./uploads/temp/".$user."/".$mx."/".$hash."/");
        rmdir("./uploads/temp/".$user."/".$mx."/");
        rmdir("./uploads/temp/".$user."/");
    }
    else
        $result=1;
    end if
} else {
    # error uploading
    $result=$errormsg;
}
```

Comment: Ahh... you see I was nearly there as I just updated my code. So you have to remove ALL dirs?

Comment: a directory has to be empty in order to delete it, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php

Comment: You should be checking the image dimensions before you plan on moving them. If the dimensions are not correct, just don't move them and they will be deleted at the the termination of the script.

Answer (score 3):

I use the [getimagesize](https://www.php.net/getimagesize) function with [GD](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) library.

Example usage:

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = @getimagesize($imageUri);

if (($height > 500) && ($width > 500)) {
    throw new Exception(sprintf('Invalid image: %d(h) and %d(w) are not within tolerable range', $height, $width));
}
```

Comment: I updated my code, please can you tell me how to use the IF HEIGHT IS SOMETHING AND WIDTH IS SOMETHING using the get function..

Comment: Some of these things you need to start figuring out on your own, i.e. reading the docs linked to from posted solutions. Updated post with sample usage.

Comment: Appreciate it. I repped you. I do check the libraries I could not find an example and get my head round this one.

Comment: Usually the comments found on PHP docs regarding specific functions are a wealth of information. It's good practice to read through them, chances are your not the first person to encounter a certain situation. If this helped, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For *getting dimensio*n Very Simple and easy with **temp_file**

```
$image_info = getimagesize($_FILES["file_field_name"]["tmp_name"]);
$image_width = $image_info[0];
$image_height = $image_info[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this? http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php

To delete the folder, it should be empty.