# Image Upload Form Dimension Validation

Tags: php

sir is it possible to check uploaded image dimension match with this dimensions 250, 468x60, 320x50, 216x36, 168x28, 300x250, 300x50

and if not match error message will like this

Image Size is not valid, available sizes are 300x250, 468x60, 320x50, 216x36, 168x28, 300x250, 300x50

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Image Upload Checking Dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317842/php-image-upload-checking-dimensions)

Comment: maybe that's for one size sir I want set accurate maltiple size matching

Comment: you can adapt the answer to suit your need, basically all you need is `getimagesize` that comes with GD library, you can then have multiple ifs or `||`

Comment: ok sir thnx for reply. let me check once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this code:-

```
$file = $_FILES["files"]['tmp_name']; // uploaded files
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
$string = $width.'x'.$height;
$predefined_sizes = array('300x250', '468x60', '320x50', '216x36', '168x28', '300x250', '300x50'); // custom image size array
if(!in_array($string,$predefined_sizes)) {
    echo "Image Size is not valid, available sizes are 300x250, 468x60, 320x50, 216x36, 168x28, 300x250, 300x50";
    // Or you can also do to avoid repetion of sizes.
    //echo "Image Size is not valid, available sizes are ".implode(', ',$predefined_sizes);
    exit;
}else{
    echo 'Valid image'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$file=$uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file)) {

    $size = getimagesize($files);

    $maxWidth = 500;  // as per your max width requerment 
    $maxHeight = 250; // as per your max hight requerment 

    if ($size[0] > $maxWidth || $size[1] > $maxHeight)
    {
        unlink($file);
        rmdir("./uploads/temp/".$user."/".$mx."/".$hash."/");
        rmdir("./uploads/temp/".$user."/".$mx."/");
        rmdir("./uploads/temp/".$user."/");

    }
    else
        echo $result= "Image Size is not valid, available sizes are 300x250, 468x60, 320x50, 216x36, 168x28, 300x250, 300x50";
    end if
} else {

   echo $result= "Not valid Image found";
}
```