# PHP using getimagesize() for image height and width

Tags: php, image, height, width

Can someone solve this error. I want to get image x and y(width,height) with form. I think I'm doing everthing well. but there's something wrong.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="img">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Resolution">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $img = $_FILES["img"]["name"];
    $dir = "x/";
    $getRes = getimagesize("x/".$img);
    echo "This is resolution of the image : ";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Image size : ".$getRes[4]."<br>";
    echo "Image width : ".$getRes[1]."<br>";
    echo "Image height : ".$getRes[0];
}
```

And it's output [You can check out here](https://ibb.co/h0Rfne)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Image Upload Checking Dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317842/php-image-upload-checking-dimensions)

Comment: Try changing $getRes = getimagesize("x/".$img); to $getRes = getimagesize("/x/".$img); Also you have variable $dir = "x/"; - you don't use it anywhere.

Comment: Thanks problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your getimagesize like this :

$getRes = getimagesize($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"]);

It's take the tempory file path to check it it's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code 
from

```
$img = $_FILES["img"]["name"];
```

To

```
$img = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it will work-

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
// change name to tmp_name because every file uploaded is saved in temporary location before saving it to actual location
    $img = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
// take base name of the uploaded file
    $name = basename($_FILES["img"]["name"];
    $dir = "x/";
// move it from temporary to $dir location 
    move_uploaded_file($img, "$dir/$name");
    $getRes = getimagesize("x/".$img);
    echo "This is resolution of the image : ";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Image size : ".$getRes[4]."<br>";
    echo "Image width : ".$getRes[1]."<br>";
    echo "Image height : ".$getRes[0];
}
```